# Automate accessing web browser and do same steps

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I have a one task that I have to enter same website and login and do always same steps in twice everyday. So i am searching for a tool that could do it for me.

Do you have any advice that can i make a macro or some robots ? I download the autohotkey already but it doesn't solve my problem so any helps are appreciated.

EDIT : I found something called [IMacros](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Chrome). It works really great.

Comment: There are a lot of examples on stackoverflow about imacros if you get stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The Internet Explorer COM object is a great way to do it with Autohotkey. It requires some advanced skills though. For most browsers there are autologin add ons. Just google for it. ;)